# print all file name with zero data contents in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to find a command to list all files under current directory with zero data contents. the zero content file size maybe different.

Below command can list all files:

```
find . -type f
```

I need only list zero content files (not zero length file, but file contents all zeros just like below:

```
xxd -g 1 test.zero                                                                           
00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

Comment: I don't know what `xxd` is, but you seem to mean a text file containing nothing but `0`, space and line feed. Is that correct?

Comment: have you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295493/how-to-find-all-files-containing-only-hex-zeroes

Answer (score 0):

you can try below command for getting empty files

sudo find . -type f -empty

Comment: Thanks, I mean not file size 0, but the file contains data all zeros and any length